# On Click When Button is Disabling then Click Button is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When I am Clicking on button of asp.net then on client click I am disabling that clicked button then server side click event is not firing.

My code is as following:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSend2" runat="server" CssClass="CommonButtonStyle" Text="Send Message" OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';return OnClickSendEmail();"
OnClick="btnSend_Click" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroupCompose" />
```

and This is my Java script code:

```
function OnClickSendEmail() {
    var value = document.getElementById('CE_ctl00_ContentMain_TextArea_ID').getHTML().replace(/&nbsp;/g, "").trim();
    if (value == "" || value == undefined) {
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').text('Message body can\'t be blank!');
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').show()    
        return false;
    } else {
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').text('');
        console.log("Value is returing true");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try and add UseSubmitBehavior="false" to the asp:Button

Comment: Yeah I have tried this also

Comment: When I use this then button does not disable and no event fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the button is disabled, the postback is not made. You could re-enable the button at the end of the processing but there is another problem: the display will not be updated when the browser is busy processing `OnClickSendEmail()`, so the button will never look disabled.

Here is a possible solution, which involves canceling the postback at first and processing the command asynchronously:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSend2" runat="server" OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; setTimeout(OnClickSendEmail, 0); return false;" ... />
```

The postback is then triggered with `__doPostBack` at the end of the lengthy processing:

```
function OnClickSendEmail() {
    var value = document.getElementById('CE_ctl00_ContentMain_TextArea_ID').getHTML().replace(/&nbsp;/g, "").trim();
    if (value == "" || value == undefined) {
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').text('Message body can\'t be blank!');
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').show()    
    } else {
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').text('');
        console.log("Value is returing true");
        __doPostBack('<%= ButtonSend2.UniqueID %>', '');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your javascript code, there are two points that can cause not firing at the end. I write on the code the possible points. Also you have include it on `ValidationGroupCompose` validation, are you sure that is not stopped from there ?

```
function OnClickSendEmail() {
    // !!! if the element not found is throw an error here and not continue at all.
    var value = document.getElementById('CE_ctl00_ContentMain_TextArea_ID').getHTML().replace(/&nbsp;/g, "").trim();
    if (value == "" || value == undefined) {
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').text('Message body can\'t be blank!');
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').show()    
        // !!!! if comes here and return false, then is NOT firing, not continue.
        return false;
    } else {
        $j('#ctl00_ContentMain_lblMessage').text('');
        // !!!! if comes here and you not use a browser that support the console, function, is thrown an error and not continue to fire up.
        console.log("Value is returing true");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Debug your javascript to see whats going wrong, also remove the `console.log` from your final code.

Comment: Sorry This is Also Not Working